# get particular day between a data range from giving table

Tags: oracle

I read many articles which introduce the using of `connect by`, but all of them get the particular days from a giving parameter(almost the begin date and end date)
What I want to know is how could I get split the rows from a certain table?
Example

```
Table T1
StartDate      EndDate        T_ID
2017-06-01     2017-06-15      01
2017-06-05     2017-06-06      02
```

The result I want is

```
TargetDate    T_ID
2017-06-01    01
2017-06-02    01
2017-06-03    01
2017-06-04    01
2017-06-05    01
.
.
.
.
2017-06-15    01
2017-06-06    01
2017-06-06    02
```

I tried

```
 SELECT T_ID, T1.StartDate+ LEVEL - 1 DD, LEVEL 
 FROM T1 
 WHERE T1.T_ID in = '01' 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (TO_DATE(TRUNC(T1.EndDate)) - T1.StartDate + 1 ) ;
```

Waiting for your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please add what you already tried and don't ask for a solution directly as this will be voted for closure. Instead, add some formatting to your question, write here what you already tried and ask for advice (**not a solution directly**).

Comment: Thanks for formatting. I tried to retrive data by                              
 SELECT  T_ID,
        T1.StartDate+ LEVEL - 1  DD,
        LEVEL
    FROM T1  
    where T1.T_ID in = '01'
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (TO_DATE(TRUNC(T1.EndDate))  - T1.StartDate  + 1 ) 
    ;

Comment: Why there is only one day `2017-06-06` for `t_id = 02` in the result you want. What's happened to `2017-06-05`? If you want only distinct dates, how would you like to handle different T_IDs that are associated with the same date?

Comment: Thanks ..I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( t_id, startdate, enddate ) AS
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-06-01', DATE '2017-06-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-06-05', DATE '2017-06-06' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT  T_ID,
        COLUMN_VALUE AS dt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.ROWID
                            ORDER BY Column_value ) AS lvl 
FROM    T1
        CROSS JOIN
        TABLE(
          CAST(
            MUTLTSET(
              SELECT     t1.Startdate + LEVEL - 1
              FROM       DUAL
              CONNECT BY t1.Startdate + LEVEL - 1 <= t1.EndDate
            ) AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST
          )
        );
```

**Output**:

```
T_ID DT         LVL
---- ---------- ---
   1 2017-06-01   1
   1 2017-06-02   2
   1 2017-06-03   3
   1 2017-06-04   4
   1 2017-06-05   5
   1 2017-06-06   6
   1 2017-06-07   7
   1 2017-06-08   8
   1 2017-06-09   9
   1 2017-06-10  10
   1 2017-06-11  11
   1 2017-06-12  12
   1 2017-06-13  13
   1 2017-06-14  14
   1 2017-06-15  15
   2 2017-06-05   1
   2 2017-06-06   2
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying. Seems the exception 01436. 00000 -  "CONNECT BY loop in user data" is warning...

Comment: Thanks for updating. the latest query get only the startDate but not splitting them

Comment: Sorry....still didnt work..00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: @Lobs works for me in Oracle 11g. Which "table or view" does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query in standard SQL (with a recursive cte) which also works in Oracle:

```
with all_dates(targetdate, t_id, enddate) as
(
  select startdate as targetdate, t_id, enddate from t1
  union all
  select targetdate + 1, t_id, enddate from all_dates where targetdate < enddate
)
select targetdate, t_id 
from all_dates
order by t_id, targetdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T_ID
      , T1.StartDate+ LEVEL - 1 DD
      , LEVEL     
FROM T1 
WHERE T1.T_ID IN( 1,2)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= T1.EndDate - T1.StartDate + 1
```

But I'm not sure about performances (At moment I didn't find a way to limit without DISTINCT but using CONNECT BY clauses).

As an alternative you can use a CTE like this (you can remove RN column, I left it as a check):

```
with all_dates(targetdate, t_id, enddate, RN) as
(
  select startdate as targetdate, t_id, enddate, 1 AS RN from t1
  union all
  select T1.startdate + all_dates.RN, T1.t_id, T1.enddate, all_dates.RN+1 AS RN
  from t1 
  inner JOIN all_dates ON T1.startdate+all_dates.RN<=all_dates.enddate
   AND T1.T_ID = all_dates.T_ID
)
select targetdate, t_id , RN
from all_dates
order by t_id, targetdate;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE, T_ID NUMBER(10,0));
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('20170601','20170615', 1);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('20170605','20170606', 2);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('20170701','20170703', 3);
```

Output:

```
20170601    1   1
20170602    1   2
20170603    1   3
20170604    1   4
20170605    1   5
20170606    1   6
20170607    1   7
20170608    1   8
20170609    1   9
20170610    1   10
20170611    1   11
20170612    1   12
20170613    1   13
20170614    1   14
20170615    1   15
20170605    2   1
20170606    2   2
20170701    3   1
20170702    3   2
20170703    3   3
```

Comment: The first hierarchical query will generate an exponential number of rows as the number of inputs - you are getting rid of them with `DISTINCT` but it is very inefficient.

Comment: I updated that comment - remove the `DISTINCT` keyword and add a few more rows with large ranges and you will quickly see the exponential growth of the query output and how inefficient it will get. The recursive query is also a version of [Thorsten Kettner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007562/1509264) that adds in an unnecessary self-join.

Comment: @MT0 : I wrote " I'm not sure about performances".  I just posted to let him view something.  Actually, from the question, we don't know how many records will be in the table (maybe just two).  And then I gave another alternative.   PS: I don't think it's correct to update the comment: now one can think my first comment to you is not motivated...

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use connect by to achieve this, you will need to add a couple of additional clauses in order to get it to work with multiple rows:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT to_date('01/06/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') startdate, to_date('15/06/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enddate, 1 t_id FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT to_date('05/06/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') startdate, to_date('06/06/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') enddate, 2 t_id FROM dual)
SELECT t_id,
       startdate + LEVEL -1 dd
FROM   t1
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= enddate - startdate + 1
AND        PRIOR t_id = t_id
AND        PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t_id, dd;

      T_ID DD
---------- -----------
         1 01/06/2017
         1 02/06/2017
         1 03/06/2017
         1 04/06/2017
         1 05/06/2017
         1 06/06/2017
         1 07/06/2017
         1 08/06/2017
         1 09/06/2017
         1 10/06/2017
         1 11/06/2017
         1 12/06/2017
         1 13/06/2017
         1 14/06/2017
         1 15/06/2017
         2 05/06/2017
         2 06/06/2017
```